# Questions on Reads and validation in Play Framework

Tags: json, playframework

1) I can create complex reads as follows:

```
implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double] and
  (JsPath \ "long").read[Double]
)(Location.apply _)
```

Where is 'and' defined? I looked up for play.libs.api.functional.syntax._ but couldn't find ths package in documentation?

2) In above code, (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double] would return another JsPath. How is 'and' taking this JsPath and combining it with (JsPath \ "long").read[Double]/

3) I can create custom validations as follows:

```
val improvedNameReads =
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String](minLength[String](2))
```

Where is Reads.minLength defined? I looked for it in Reads.scala but couldn't find it there.

Comment: I think I understood the 3rd doubt - read is defined as `read[T](implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[T]`. So minLength is the argument to read i.e. it is 'r'. Am I correct?

Comment: Also find minLength is defined at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads$

Answer (score 0):

It's called

> Applicative functor

Here is the explanation of concrete realization JSON formats in play:

http://mandubian.com/2012/09/08/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part1-jspath-reads-combinators/

https://gist.github.com/sadache/3646092#file-2-functionalbuilder-scala

You can find much more on the internet, like this:

https://softwaremill.com/applicative-functor/

Your code uses the `and` that is coded in the `Products.scala`:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/Products.scala